# Object not found! url rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have rewrited my url's with htaccess and now I the following URL

This is my old URL:

```
http://example.com/user.php?username=collins1
```

The new URL:

```
http://example.com/user/collins1/
```

The .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^user\.php$ %{QUERY_STRING} [C]
RewriteRule ^username=(.*) /user/$1/? [R=301,L]
```

It get an Object not found! response, kindly help

Comment: That is an unusual style. What does RewriteLog / LogLevel rewrite:trace8 say is happening?

Comment: @covener how do i see that

Comment: @covener although am running on xampp

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting not rewriting your url, for internal rewrite use this

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/$ /user.php?username=$1 [L]`